# In the jQuery Galleria plugin, pressing the right key moves to the next image. How can I access this method from the page where I use the plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm very new to javascript & jQuery, and can't work out how to do this. The source code can be found [here](http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/src/galleria.js). Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API isn't very well documented here, but when you run [`.galleria()`](http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/src/galleria.js#L1453), it [returns the gallery object](http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/src/galleria.js#L1479), so you can hang on to a reference to it, like this:

```
var gallery = $('#galleria').galleria();
```

Then you can use it later to move like you want:

```
gallery.next(); //move next
gallery.prev(); //move back
```

Here you're just accessing the [`next`](http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/src/galleria.js#L1125) and [`prev`](http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/src/galleria.js#L1132) functions defined on the gallery object returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm re-answering this since the plugin just had a new revision where the accepted answer wont work anymore.

The best way is to use the extend method to attach events to external elements. See the demo available here: http://galleria.aino.se/media/galleria/demos/classic-03.html

You can also fetch the Galleria instance anywhere, like Nick wrote, using:

```
var gallery = Galleria.get(0); // fetches the first instance

gallery.next();
gallery.prev();
```

The API has been updated here: http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/docs/

Have a look at public-methods, events and static-methods.